# Facing bug while using add_module() in pytorch to add new modules in one single class

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am new to pytorch. The code I have written is as shown below.

```
import torch
from torch import nn 
from torch.nn import functional as F 

class MySequential(nn.Module):
    """
    This is the sequential module which will be used to append modules into.
    
    """

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MySequential, self).__init__()

        for idx, module in enumerate(args):
            self.add_module(str(idx), module)

    def forward(self, X):
            """
            Accessing modules added in MySequential module using self.children() method from inherited from nn.Module()
            
            """
            for module in self.children():
                X = module(X)

                return X



##################################################################################################################################################
"""
The following code will create a random input with torch.rand() and will apply it to the module and get the output.

"""
input = torch.rand(500)
print('The shape of the input is: ', input.shape)
net = MySequential(nn.LazyLinear(256), nn.ReLU(), nn.LazyLinear(10))
out = net(input)
print('The shape of the output is: ', out.shape)
```

according to me the last module in the sequence is `nn.LazyLinear(10)` so the output should be of size 10. When I run this code, I am getting the following output.

```
The shape of the input is:  torch.Size([500])
The shape of the output is:  torch.Size([256])
```

Can someone please explain why the size of the output is 256 and not 10? I tried to debug. The only conclusion I can draw is ReLu layer and the output layers are not executed by the program, but I am not able to understand why.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. `return X` is inside the for loop so you're returning the output of the first layer.

Comment: @jodag Yes, that was the problem. Thank you for response.